# How to save and load in OpenGL

Tags: c++

How to save all things drawn in OpenGL into text files and load context in text files into OpenGL programs? (I want to find opengl C++ statements executing this job)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems like the author hasn'r made a minimal research regarding what OpenGL is and what it is not.

Comment: The teacher gave me an exercise that drawing logic gates, then saving them as text file and loading them into program. I look up Google but there is no answer

Answer (score 4):

OpenGL is not responsible of storing any instructions of how to draw the scene. It is your responsibility to resubmit those instructions each frame you draw, based on **your** data structure in **your** code. So it's your responsibility of dumping that data structure to a file and reloading it later. This is entirely depends on how your code is structured, and is entirely unrelated to OpenGL.

Answer (score 1):

OpenGL just draws points, lines and triangles. One at a time, without the concept of a "scene" or "meshes" or "models". The end result is framebuffer which pixels got their values changed whereever point, lines or triangles were drawn.

OpenGL **does not**:

- deal with files
- load or save scenes
- load or save meshes
- maintain an abstract drawing structure

Everything OpenGL does not do you have to do yourself.